# Monitor how long UITableViewCell is displayed on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, timer

I'm trying to find the best way to save how long users of my app have looked at each UITableViewCell, for optimization and metrics purposes. I haven't found a tool (Parse, AppSee, etc) that can monitor that, so I'm doing it manually. Problem is, it's incredibly not efficient.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView; // Or however you get your table view
    NSArray *paths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    //  For getting the cells themselves
    NSMutableSet *visibleCells = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
        NSLog(@"visible: %i", path.row);
        [visibleCells addObject:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path]];
    }
}
```

I will then start a NSTimer as soon as is't visible and stop it when it's not visible anymore.
This has number of flaws:

1. When the tableview is presented, the user can look at the first cell without scrolling - thus this code isn't called.
2. This code is called tens of time a second - there must be a better way
3. This code is called when the user is looking at, for example, the second cell, but the first cell is still a few pixels visible. So there should be a condition where the call has to be at least 20% visible to make the timer active.
4. If the user taps another tab bar while looking at cells, **this code isn't aware and keeps counting**.

My solution is obviously not optimal. Have a better way? Your solution is welcome

Comment: store the time when you start the display and get the time when you stop the display. the time difference between these two is what you want.

Comment: Sounds easy in theory, but I'm trying to find the optimal code for this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the table view delegate methods and the view controller display methods. Specifically:

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
viewDidDisappear:
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually thought about this, but how would you keep of the time for each cell? Tableview methods are great to know which cell I'm currently displaying, but when the view disappears, how to stop the timer attached to the cell displayed?

Comment: I wouldn't use a timer. I'd use an array that matches your source data (in terms of `count`) which contains the accumulated time so far and a 'start time' if the cell is currently on display. When removed from display, use the 'start time' to increment the accumulated time.